Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|a|+|b|\leq 1$ and $|c|+|d|\leq 1$. Show that $|3a+b+3c-d|+|a+3b-c+3d|\leq 7$.

Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|a|+|b|\leq 1$ and $|c|+|d|\leq 1$. Show that $|3a+b+3c-d|+|a+3b-c+3d|\leq 7$, or find a counterexample -- I don't know for sure that the inequality stated in the title is true.

In the case of $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, the constraint set is a polytope and the objective is convex. Thus, simply by checking its value on all vertices $\{(\pm 1,0), (0,\pm 1)\}^2$, we see that the upper bound is $6$.
I'm not sure about the complex case though. It looks like the above approach won't work, because the feasible set has uncountably many extreme points. By naive Monte Carlo sampling it seems that the maximum is around $6.33$.

I think I have a full solution. Thanks to River Li for pointing me in the right direction.
We can reparameterize as
$$a=r_1e^{i\theta_1},\\b=r_2e^{i\theta_2},\\c=r_3e^{i\theta_3},\\d=r_4e^{i\theta_4}$$
where $r_i,\theta_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and  $r_i\geq 0$ for all $i$. The constraints become
$$r_1+r_2\leq 1, \\r_3+r_4\leq 1.$$
Note that, for fixed $\theta_i$, the objective function is convex wrt all $r_i$. Thus, as in the real case, it suffices to check the extreme points
$$
((r_1,r_2),(r_3,r_4))\in\{(1,0),(0,1),(0,0)\}^2.
$$
Due to symmetry, there are really only a few distinct cases to consider for the values of $(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4)$:

$(0,0,0,0)$: The objective value is $0$.
$(0,0,1,0)$: The objective value is $4$.
$(1,0,1,0)$: WLOG, we can rotate so that $\theta_1=0$, i.e. $a$ is real. The problem reduces to
$$\max_\theta |3+3e^{i\theta}|+|1-e^{i\theta}|=\max_\theta \sqrt{18+18\cos\theta}+\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}= 10\sqrt{2},$$
maximized at $\theta=\arccos(4/5)$.
$(1,0,0,1)$: Again, rotate so that $\theta_1=0$. The problem reduces to
$$\max_\theta |3-e^{i\theta}|+|1+e^{i\theta}|=\max_\theta \sqrt{10-6\cos\theta}+\sqrt{10+6\cos\theta}=10\sqrt{2},$$
maximized at $\theta=\pi/2$.


It is nice to use convexity.

Just some thoughts.
(i) I guess the maximum is $2\sqrt{10}$
attained at e.g.
$$a = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta},\quad b = c = 0, \quad d = \mathrm{i} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}, \quad \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R};$$
or
$$a = \frac{3 - 3b_1}{5} + \frac{4b_1-4}{5}\mathrm{i}, \quad
b = b_1, \quad c = -b_1 \mathrm{i}, \quad 
d = \frac{4 - 4b_1}{5} + \frac{3 - 3b_1}{5}\mathrm{i},$$
$$\forall b_1 \in [0, 1].$$
